# set constants and get those constant in core php and laravel as well

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on a project that has some part of it in core php and other part is in laravel . So what I want there is any I can set variables or constant and can get those constant in both environment core php and laravel and both are on same server.

Comment: I'm sure there are better answers this is just a suggestion but a value could be set in the Laravel config file. Which can be manipulated from Laravel. You could also write a class in standard PHP to parse the file.

Comment: Actually my Laravel files and core php files are in different directories . So if I set in laravel config.php file then I think I can't access them in my core php file. My cdirectory structure is as  public_html and Laravel are in same  hierarchy

Comment: Could they be set in another JSON/YAML file that both could access ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `.php` in directory and can access it in you project. Your file will be like this `<?php return ['a' => 'abc']; ?>`. Include this files and access all constants.